# Combine two sha512 hashes to a single hash

Tags: hash, cryptanalysis, algorithm-design, sha-512

Assume I have two data fragments: $Frag_1$ and $Frag_2$.

I can build sha512 hashes the usual way with $SHA512(Frag_1)$ and $SHA512(Frag_2)$ and then hash the two fragments appended to each other:

$$SHA512(Frag_1 | Frag_2)$$

My question is, is there any way to combine the hashes of those two fragments so that it would be possible to compute the hash of their appended version?

More precise: Is there an operation (denoted here with a red question mark “$\color{red} ?$”), so that

$$SHA512(Frag_1)\ \color{red} ?\ SHA512(Frag_2) == SHA512(Frag_1 | Frag_2)$$

It is possible to create the data fragments with a length of a multiple of the block size of sha512?

Comment: I don't have a proof (maybe someone else has), but I *think* this is impossible without inverting SHA-512.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_extension_attack

Comment: @HenrickHellström That extends a hash using additional data. Combining the state of one hash with another hash, which started off with the usual initial state seems another matter to me entirely.

Comment: As nicely explained in the answers, if this was possible for any Hash function, it would lead to a recursive attack and a break.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most standard-use iterative hash functions (including SHA-512) are build in a way that these types of operation are **not possible** (without breaking the hash function).

They work generally in this way:

- The message is split in same-size blocks (usually with some padding at the end to fill the last block): $pad(M) = M_0 || M_1 || M_2 ... || M_n$.
- There is some internal "state" $S$, initialized to a fixed value $S_0$ at the start
- For each block, some internal function $C$ (usually called a "compression function") is applied to the old state and a message block to produce a new state: $S_{i+1} = C(S_i, M_i)$
- At the end, either the last state is output directly, or (in more modern hash functions) another function $O$ is applied on that state to produce the final hash output: $h(M) = O(S_{n+1})$

So for example with a 4-block message (after padding) we have $$h(M) =  O(C(C(C(C(S_0, M_0), M_1), M_2), M_3)).$$

The compression functions are usually build in a way that even a minor change in one of the inputs produces a totally different output, and such that there is no easy way to go back from the output to the input. (This is usually formalized as *"$C$ is a one-way function"*.) (Sometimes parts of the state are treated specially and can be easily tracked back, like in Skein, where they contain a counter. This is not the case for SHA-256, and also in Skein this doesn't hurt anything, as the output doesn't include them.)

Even assuming there is no padding, O is the identity and our fragments have both the size of only one block, we get $h(F_1) = C(S_0, F_1)$, $h(F_2) = C(S_0, F_2)$ and
$h(F_1||F_2)) = C(C(S_0, F_1), F_2)$.
While we can write the latter also as $h(F_1||F_2)) = C(h(F1), F_2)$, the one-way property of the compression function doesn't allow us to get any information about this from $C(S_0, F_2)$.

But if you have $F_2$ actually given, not just its hash, you can use this to create the hash of $F_1||F_2$, even without knowing $F_1$. This is known as the length-extension property of iterative hashes with the identity as its output transformation.
<sub>In reality it is complicated by the presence of a padding, but you still get to create the hash for something like $F_1 || P || F_2$, where you know $h(F_1)$ (but not $F_1$ itself), $P$ is some padding depending on the length of $F_1$ (and not actually needed to be known by you), and $F_2$ is a string chosen by you).</sub>

Using a non-trivial output transformation blocks this – possible ways are to apply some simple truncation (like SHA-384, which is essentially SHA-512 with a different initial state and a truncation of the result), or some other compression-function-like transformation. Or simply apply the whole hash function again on the result (this is used e.g. as SHA-256d in the Bitcoin protocol).

---

On the other hand, there are hash functions which are specifically designed to allow stuff like that: hashing two (or more) parts of the message separately and create the final hash from the partial hashes.

Have a look at the [Merkle tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree) article in Wikipedia, it explains the basic principles. When used as a simple message hash algorithm (and not a complex structure), for it to have a deterministic result, the size of $F_1$ needs to be one of some few specific values (e.g. powers of two), so the limit between $F_1$ and $F_2$ falls exactly on a border between two subtrees.

Comment: I suspected as much, thank you for the very detailed and well understandable explanation!

Comment: Is there a common name for the "hash functions which are specifically designed to allow stuff like that"?

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not possible, as you calculate `sha512(F2)` without the state of `sha512(F1)`. What you require is `compress(mix(compress(mix(IH, F1)), F2))` while what you have is `compress(mix(IH, F1))` and `compress(mix(IH, F2))`. So you would have to undo that last compression, which is obviously not possible.

Here `IH` is the initial state (the values of $h_1$ etc.) for SHA-1 or [SHA-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2).