# Collision-resistance of $H\Bigl(\bigl(H(m_1\mathbin\| 1)\oplus H(m_2\mathbin\|2)\oplus\dots\oplus H(m_n\mathbin\|n)\bigr)\mathbin\|n\Bigr)$?

Tags: hash, collision-resistance

In [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/56489/555) and [discussion](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74567/discussion-on-answer-by-cypherfox-are-there-better-alternatives-to-crc32-for-dis), it is considered a distributable hash

$$\tilde H(m)\ =\ H\Bigl(\bigl(H(m_1\mathbin\| 1)\oplus H(m_2\mathbin\|2)\oplus\dots\oplus H(m_n\mathbin\|n)\bigr)\mathbin\|n\Bigr)$$

where the $m_i$ are $n$ segments (say of fixed size) of message $m$, and $H$ is a cryptographic hash (say of $b$-bit and assumed secure in the ROM).

What can we say about the collision-resistance of $\tilde H$ as a function of $b$ ?

Comment: Thanks for questioning my handrolled crypto! Whoops! Although IIUC it is still a valid answer, just weaker than I realised.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> What can we say about the collision-resistance of $\tilde H$ as a function of $b$ ?

That it is effectively nonexistent; it is easy to generate collisions (and second preimages).

You can generate a second preimage by selecting two blocks $m'_i, m''_i$ to correspond to each original block $m_i$; you compute $H(m'_i \mathbin\| i), H(m''_i \mathbin\| i)$, and then use linear algebra (e.g. Gaussian Elimination) to see which combination of $m'_i, m''_i$ all xor the same as the original sequence of $m_i$; that combination hashes to the same value.  As long as the original message is at least $b$ blocks long (that is, $n \ge b$), such a combination exists with good probability.

Once you can create second preimages, you can generate collisions by picking a message and generating a second preimage for it.

Comment: Would this not imply an attack against PMAC? Or does the keyed-PRP defend against this? What about if we fix the key?

Comment: @cypherfox: it doesn't apply to PMAC, because in PMAC, the $H$ function (using the above terminology) uses a secret key (and hence the attacker can't compute it directly).  If you fix the key, well yes, PMAC rather falls apart (as do a bunch of other MACs); MACs (in general) have no guaranteed security properties if the attacker knows the key

Comment: Well that is unfortunate. :/

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: OR maybe my answer is still valid as they don't ask for collision resistance and intend to use it for weak-integrity (where CRC is valid) and we already don't trust the distributed participants. Thoughts?

Comment: Reference: M. Bellare and D. Micciancio, ‘A New Paradigm for collision-free hashing: Incrementality at reduced cost’, In W. Fumy, _ed._, _Advances in Cryptology—EUROCRYPT'97_, Springer LNCS 1233, 1997.  [Full paper](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~mihir/papers/inchash.pdf), where it is called XHASH with details on poncho's answer in Appendix A, and [related work](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~mihir/papers/incremental.html).

Answer (score 5):

While the other answer is correct, I want to point out that the construction is theoretically collision-resistant when $n$ is a  fixed constant (independent of the security parameter) and $H$ is modeled as a random oracle.

Specifically, to find a collision, the adversary would (with overwhelming probability) have to find a structure like $H(m_1 \| 1) \oplus \cdots \oplus H(m_n \| n) = H(m'_1 \| 1) \oplus \cdots \oplus H(m'_n \| n) $. For a random oracle with $b$ output bits, and an adversary who makes $q$ queries, the probability of any subset of the queries satisfying such a relation is at most $q^{2n}/2^b$.

$q^{2n}/2^b$ is technically a negligible function, which makes this construction technically collision resistant in the asymptotic sense.  But it's really bad/impractical, since in practice your parameters should satisfy $b\ge 256n$.

Comment: Limited to the case $n = 4$, this is the basic conceit of [Rumba](https://cr.yp.to/rumba20.html), which may be worth citing here.